# How can I extract rectangles using itext7 from pdf in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, shapes, itext7, data-extraction

I want to extract the rectangles from pdf with their location and fill color. Please help me if anyone here has some idea about extraction of rectangle shapes from pdf using itext7 in vb.net

Comment: What kind of rectangles? Rectangles from bitmap images, from vector graphics, from fonts?

Comment: Rectangles from vector graphics. Simply the shapes like circle rectangles, rounded rectangle- I have to extract all these  geometric shape from pdf

Comment: Ah, that's different. In your question you only mentioned rectangles, now it's essentially arbitrary shapes... Nonetheless, it's easy to extract paths with their fill color (as long as it's a "normal" fill color, not a pattern fill or a path in a soft mask or something similarly special) but it would be your task to recognize what kind of shape that path represents. Would an answer along those lines help?

Comment: I am very new to pdf extraction and itext. It would be great and very helpful if you can help with some code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As it turned out in comments, the forms the OP is interested in are vector graphics but not only rectangles but essentially arbitrary shapes. Thus, this answer demonstrates how to extract vector graphics paths and their use (stroke/fill/...) using vb.net.*

For data extraction from PDFs iText 7 provides a framework that follows the instructions in a PDF content stream and triggers events accordingly. To extract the paths, therefore, you have to first of all implement an event listener (implementing the iText `IEventListener` interface). This implementation then needs to select only the required events (with `EventType.RENDER_PATH`) and extract the desired information from the given `PathRenderInfo` event data object.

The following example event listener class simply prints the path information to the console:

```vb
Public Class PathListener
    Implements IEventListener

    Public Sub EventOccurred(data As IEventData, type As EventType) Implements IEventListener.EventOccurred
        If type = EventType.RENDER_PATH Then
            Dim PathRenderInfo As PathRenderInfo = CType(data, PathRenderInfo)
            Dim OperationData = GetOperationData(PathRenderInfo)
            Dim PathData = GetPathData(PathRenderInfo)
            Console.WriteLine("{1} - {0}", OperationData, PathData)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetSupportedEvents() As ICollection(Of EventType) Implements IEventListener.GetSupportedEvents
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Function GetOperationData(PathRenderInfo As PathRenderInfo) As String
        Dim OperationBuilder As New StringBuilder
        If PathRenderInfo.GetOperation = PathRenderInfo.NO_OP Then
            OperationBuilder.Append("Invisible")
        End If
        If (PathRenderInfo.GetOperation And PathRenderInfo.STROKE) = PathRenderInfo.STROKE Then
            OperationBuilder.Append("Stroked with ").Append(GetColorData(PathRenderInfo.GetStrokeColor))
            If (PathRenderInfo.GetOperation And PathRenderInfo.FILL) = PathRenderInfo.FILL Then
                OperationBuilder.Append(" and ")
            End If
        End If
        If (PathRenderInfo.GetOperation And PathRenderInfo.FILL) = PathRenderInfo.FILL Then
            OperationBuilder.Append("Filled with ").Append(GetColorData(PathRenderInfo.GetFillColor))
        End If
        If (PathRenderInfo.IsPathModifiesClippingPath) Then
            OperationBuilder.Append(", clipping")
        End If
        Return OperationBuilder.ToString
    End Function

    Function GetColorData(Color As Color) As String
        Dim ColorBuilder As New StringBuilder
        If TypeOf Color Is CalGray Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("CalGray")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is CalRgb Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("CalRGB")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is DeviceCmyk Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("DeviceCmyk")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is DeviceGray Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("DeviceGray")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is DeviceN Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("DeviceN")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is DeviceRgb Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("DeviceRgb")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is IccBased Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("IccBased")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is Indexed Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("Indexed")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is Lab Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("Lab")
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is PatternColor Then
            Return "PatternColor(special)"
        ElseIf TypeOf Color Is Separation Then
            ColorBuilder.Append("Separation")
        End If
        ColorBuilder.Append("(").Append(String.Join(", ", Color.GetColorValue)).Append(")")
        Return ColorBuilder.ToString
    End Function

    Function GetPathData(PathRenderInfo As PathRenderInfo) As String
        Dim CurrentTransformation = PathRenderInfo.GetCtm
        Dim PathBuilder As New StringBuilder
        Dim FirstSubPath = True
        For Each SubPath In PathRenderInfo.GetPath.GetSubpaths
            If FirstSubPath Then
                FirstSubPath = False
                PathBuilder.Append("Path ")
            ElseIf Not (SubPath.IsEmpty Or SubPath.GetSegments.Count = 0) Then
                PathBuilder.Append(" and ")
            End If
            Dim FirstShape = True
            For Each Shape In SubPath.GetSegments
                If FirstShape Then
                    FirstShape = False
                    PathBuilder.Append("from ").Append(GetPointData(Shape.GetBasePoints.First, CurrentTransformation))
                Else
                    PathBuilder.Append(",")
                End If
                If TypeOf Shape Is Line Then
                    PathBuilder.Append(" line to ").Append(GetPointData(Shape.GetBasePoints.Last, CurrentTransformation))
                ElseIf TypeOf Shape Is BezierCurve Then
                    PathBuilder.Append(" curve via ").Append(GetPointData(Shape.GetBasePoints(1), CurrentTransformation))
                    PathBuilder.Append(" and ").Append(GetPointData(Shape.GetBasePoints(2), CurrentTransformation))
                    PathBuilder.Append(" to ").Append(GetPointData(Shape.GetBasePoints(3), CurrentTransformation))
                End If
            Next
            If SubPath.IsClosed Then
                PathBuilder.Append(" (closed)")
            End If
        Next
        Return PathBuilder.ToString
    End Function

    Function GetPointData(Point As Point, CurrentTransformation As Matrix) As String
        Dim Transformed = CurrentTransformation.Multiply(New Matrix(Point.GetX, Point.GetY))
        Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "({0}, {1})", Transformed.Get(Matrix.I31), Transformed.Get(Matrix.I32))
    End Function
End Class
```

Using this event listener you can inspect the pages of your document:

```vb
Using PdfDocument As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(...))
    Dim PathListener As New PathListener
    Dim PdfCanvasProcessor As New PdfCanvasProcessor(PathListener)
    For page As Integer = 1 To PdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages
        PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfDocument.GetPage(page))
    Next
End Using
```

The output then may look like this:

```
Path from (51.2, 723.57) line to (512.17, 723.57), line to (512.17, 736.97), line to (51.2, 736.97) (closed) - Invisible, clipping
Path from (108.6, 516.6) curve via (108.6, 569.29) and (160.18, 612) to (223.8, 612), curve via (287.42, 612) and (339, 569.29) to (339, 516.6), curve via (339, 463.91) and (287.42, 421.2) to (223.8, 421.2), curve via (160.18, 421.2) and (108.6, 463.91) to (108.6, 516.6) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (174.89, 545.13) curve via (174.89, 550.62) and (180.27, 555.07) to (186.89, 555.07), curve via (193.52, 555.07) and (198.89, 550.62) to (198.89, 545.13), curve via (198.89, 539.64) and (193.52, 535.19) to (186.89, 535.19), curve via (180.27, 535.19) and (174.89, 539.64) to (174.89, 545.13) (closed) and from (248.71, 545.13) curve via (248.71, 550.62) and (254.08, 555.07) to (260.71, 555.07), curve via (267.33, 555.07) and (272.71, 550.62) to (272.71, 545.13), curve via (272.71, 539.64) and (267.33, 535.19) to (260.71, 535.19), curve via (254.08, 535.19) and (248.71, 539.64) to (248.71, 545.13) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.251, 0.408, 0.596)
Path from (174.89, 545.13) curve via (174.89, 550.62) and (180.27, 555.07) to (186.89, 555.07), curve via (193.52, 555.07) and (198.89, 550.62) to (198.89, 545.13), curve via (198.89, 539.64) and (193.52, 535.19) to (186.89, 535.19), curve via (180.27, 535.19) and (174.89, 539.64) to (174.89, 545.13) (closed) and from (248.71, 545.13) curve via (248.71, 550.62) and (254.08, 555.07) to (260.71, 555.07), curve via (267.33, 555.07) and (272.71, 550.62) to (272.71, 545.13), curve via (272.71, 539.64) and (267.33, 535.19) to (260.71, 535.19), curve via (254.08, 535.19) and (248.71, 539.64) to (248.71, 545.13) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (161.36, 475) curve via (202.99, 451.32) and (244.56, 451.32) to (286.09, 475) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (108.6, 516.6) curve via (108.6, 569.29) and (160.18, 612) to (223.8, 612), curve via (287.42, 612) and (339, 569.29) to (339, 516.6), curve via (339, 463.91) and (287.42, 421.2) to (223.8, 421.2), curve via (160.18, 421.2) and (108.6, 463.91) to (108.6, 516.6) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (51.2, 565.15) line to (512.17, 565.15), line to (512.17, 578.55), line to (51.2, 578.55) (closed) - Invisible, clipping
Path from (147.8, 556.2) curve via (147.8, 608.89) and (199.38, 651.6) to (263, 651.6), curve via (326.62, 651.6) and (378.2, 608.89) to (378.2, 556.2), curve via (378.2, 503.51) and (326.62, 460.8) to (263, 460.8), curve via (199.38, 460.8) and (147.8, 503.51) to (147.8, 556.2) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (214.09, 584.73) curve via (214.09, 590.22) and (219.47, 594.67) to (226.09, 594.67), curve via (232.72, 594.67) and (238.09, 590.22) to (238.09, 584.73), curve via (238.09, 579.24) and (232.72, 574.79) to (226.09, 574.79), curve via (219.47, 574.79) and (214.09, 579.24) to (214.09, 584.73) (closed) and from (287.91, 584.73) curve via (287.91, 590.22) and (293.28, 594.67) to (299.91, 594.67), curve via (306.53, 594.67) and (311.91, 590.22) to (311.91, 584.73), curve via (311.91, 579.24) and (306.53, 574.79) to (299.91, 574.79), curve via (293.28, 574.79) and (287.91, 579.24) to (287.91, 584.73) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.251, 0.408, 0.596)
Path from (214.09, 584.73) curve via (214.09, 590.22) and (219.47, 594.67) to (226.09, 594.67), curve via (232.72, 594.67) and (238.09, 590.22) to (238.09, 584.73), curve via (238.09, 579.24) and (232.72, 574.79) to (226.09, 574.79), curve via (219.47, 574.79) and (214.09, 579.24) to (214.09, 584.73) (closed) and from (287.91, 584.73) curve via (287.91, 590.22) and (293.28, 594.67) to (299.91, 594.67), curve via (306.53, 594.67) and (311.91, 590.22) to (311.91, 584.73), curve via (311.91, 579.24) and (306.53, 574.79) to (299.91, 574.79), curve via (293.28, 574.79) and (287.91, 579.24) to (287.91, 584.73) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (200.56, 514.6) curve via (242.19, 490.92) and (283.76, 490.92) to (325.29, 514.6) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (147.8, 556.2) curve via (147.8, 608.89) and (199.38, 651.6) to (263, 651.6), curve via (326.62, 651.6) and (378.2, 608.89) to (378.2, 556.2), curve via (378.2, 503.51) and (326.62, 460.8) to (263, 460.8), curve via (199.38, 460.8) and (147.8, 503.51) to (147.8, 556.2) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (103, 398.43) line to (487, 398.43), line to (487, 605.83), line to (103, 605.83) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (103, 398.43) line to (487, 398.43), line to (487, 605.83), line to (103, 605.83) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceGray(0.525)
Path from (229.4, 344.2) curve via (229.4, 363.31) and (246.59, 378.8) to (267.8, 378.8), curve via (289.01, 378.8) and (306.2, 363.31) to (306.2, 344.2), curve via (306.2, 325.09) and (289.01, 309.6) to (267.8, 309.6), curve via (246.59, 309.6) and (229.4, 325.09) to (229.4, 344.2) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (229.4, 344.2) curve via (229.4, 363.31) and (246.59, 378.8) to (267.8, 378.8), curve via (289.01, 378.8) and (306.2, 363.31) to (306.2, 344.2), curve via (306.2, 325.09) and (289.01, 309.6) to (267.8, 309.6), curve via (246.59, 309.6) and (229.4, 325.09) to (229.4, 344.2) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (237.4, 256.57) line to (266.74, 256.57), line to (275.8, 283), line to (284.86, 256.57), line to (314.2, 256.57), line to (290.47, 240.23), line to (299.53, 213.8), line to (275.8, 230.14), line to (252.07, 213.8), line to (261.13, 240.23) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (237.4, 256.57) line to (266.74, 256.57), line to (275.8, 283), line to (284.86, 256.57), line to (314.2, 256.57), line to (290.47, 240.23), line to (299.53, 213.8), line to (275.8, 230.14), line to (252.07, 213.8), line to (261.13, 240.23) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (163, 432.4) curve via (163, 485.09) and (216.9, 527.8) to (283.4, 527.8), curve via (349.9, 527.8) and (403.8, 485.09) to (403.8, 432.4), curve via (403.8, 379.71) and (349.9, 337) to (283.4, 337), curve via (216.9, 337) and (163, 379.71) to (163, 432.4) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (232.29, 460.93) curve via (232.29, 466.42) and (237.9, 470.87) to (244.83, 470.87), curve via (251.75, 470.87) and (257.37, 466.42) to (257.37, 460.93), curve via (257.37, 455.44) and (251.75, 450.99) to (244.83, 450.99), curve via (237.9, 450.99) and (232.29, 455.44) to (232.29, 460.93) (closed) and from (309.43, 460.93) curve via (309.43, 466.42) and (315.05, 470.87) to (321.97, 470.87), curve via (328.9, 470.87) and (334.51, 466.42) to (334.51, 460.93), curve via (334.51, 455.44) and (328.9, 450.99) to (321.97, 450.99), curve via (315.05, 450.99) and (309.43, 455.44) to (309.43, 460.93) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.251, 0.408, 0.596)
Path from (232.29, 460.93) curve via (232.29, 466.42) and (237.9, 470.87) to (244.83, 470.87), curve via (251.75, 470.87) and (257.37, 466.42) to (257.37, 460.93), curve via (257.37, 455.44) and (251.75, 450.99) to (244.83, 450.99), curve via (237.9, 450.99) and (232.29, 455.44) to (232.29, 460.93) (closed) and from (309.43, 460.93) curve via (309.43, 466.42) and (315.05, 470.87) to (321.97, 470.87), curve via (328.9, 470.87) and (334.51, 466.42) to (334.51, 460.93), curve via (334.51, 455.44) and (328.9, 450.99) to (321.97, 450.99), curve via (315.05, 450.99) and (309.43, 455.44) to (309.43, 460.93) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (218.14, 390.8) curve via (261.65, 367.12) and (305.1, 367.12) to (348.51, 390.8) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (163, 432.4) curve via (163, 485.09) and (216.9, 527.8) to (283.4, 527.8), curve via (349.9, 527.8) and (403.8, 485.09) to (403.8, 432.4), curve via (403.8, 379.71) and (349.9, 337) to (283.4, 337), curve via (216.9, 337) and (163, 379.71) to (163, 432.4) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
Path from (51.2, 60.025) line to (420.15, 60.025), line to (420.15, 736.975), line to (51.2, 736.975) (closed) - Invisible, clipping
Path from (255.48, 564.55) line to (368.53, 564.55), line to (368.53, 579.15), line to (255.48, 579.15) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (255.48, 550.13) line to (368.53, 550.13), line to (368.53, 564.755), line to (255.48, 564.755) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (255.48, 521.32) line to (368.53, 521.32), line to (368.53, 535.92), line to (255.48, 535.92) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (255.48, 492.52) line to (368.53, 492.52), line to (368.53, 507.12), line to (255.48, 507.12) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (255.48, 463.73) line to (368.53, 463.73), line to (368.53, 478.33), line to (255.48, 478.33) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (255.48, 434.9) line to (368.53, 434.9), line to (368.53, 449.525), line to (255.48, 449.525) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (255.48, 406.1) line to (368.53, 406.1), line to (368.53, 420.7), line to (255.48, 420.7) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.863, 0.902, 0.945)
Path from (51.2, 565.15) line to (420.15, 565.15), line to (420.15, 578.55), line to (51.2, 578.55) (closed) - Invisible, clipping
Path from (49.2, 57.825) line to (422.35, 57.825), line to (422.35, 738.975), line to (49.2, 738.975) (closed) - Invisible, clipping
Path from (255.18, 579.45) line to (255.18, 405.8) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (255.08, 405.7) line to (256.08, 405.7), line to (256.08, 579.55), line to (255.08, 579.55) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (368.02, 578.45) line to (368.02, 405.8) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (367.93, 405.7) line to (368.93, 405.7), line to (368.93, 578.55), line to (367.93, 578.55) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 579.45) line to (368.83, 579.45) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 578.55) line to (368.93, 578.55), line to (368.93, 579.55), line to (256.08, 579.55) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 565.05) line to (368.83, 565.05) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 564.15) line to (368.93, 564.15), line to (368.93, 565.15), line to (256.08, 565.15) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 550.63) line to (368.83, 550.63) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 549.72) line to (368.93, 549.72), line to (368.93, 550.72), line to (256.08, 550.72) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 536.22) line to (368.83, 536.22) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 535.33) line to (368.93, 535.33), line to (368.93, 536.33), line to (256.08, 536.33) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 521.82) line to (368.83, 521.82) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 520.92) line to (368.93, 520.92), line to (368.93, 521.92), line to (256.08, 521.92) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 507.42) line to (368.83, 507.42) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 506.52) line to (368.93, 506.52), line to (368.93, 507.52), line to (256.08, 507.52) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 493.02) line to (368.83, 493.02) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 492.13) line to (368.93, 492.13), line to (368.93, 493.13), line to (256.08, 493.13) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 478.63) line to (368.83, 478.63) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 477.73) line to (368.93, 477.73), line to (368.93, 478.73), line to (256.08, 478.73) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 464.23) line to (368.83, 464.23) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 463.32) line to (368.93, 463.32), line to (368.93, 464.32), line to (256.08, 464.32) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 449.82) line to (368.83, 449.82) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 448.9) line to (368.93, 448.9), line to (368.93, 449.925), line to (256.08, 449.925) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 435.4) line to (368.83, 435.4) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 434.5) line to (368.93, 434.5), line to (368.93, 435.5), line to (256.08, 435.5) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 421) line to (368.83, 421) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 420.1) line to (368.93, 420.1), line to (368.93, 421.1), line to (256.08, 421.1) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.18, 406.6) line to (368.83, 406.6) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (256.08, 405.7) line to (368.93, 405.7), line to (368.93, 406.7), line to (256.08, 406.7) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.584, 0.702, 0.843)
Path from (280.6, 359.3) line to (287.93, 380.62), line to (307.13, 393.8), line to (330.87, 393.8), line to (350.07, 380.62), line to (357.4, 359.3), line to (350.07, 337.98), line to (330.87, 324.8), line to (307.13, 324.8), line to (287.93, 337.98) (closed) - Filled with DeviceRgb(0.31, 0.506, 0.741)
Path from (280.6, 359.3) line to (287.93, 380.62), line to (307.13, 393.8), line to (330.87, 393.8), line to (350.07, 380.62), line to (357.4, 359.3), line to (350.07, 337.98), line to (330.87, 324.8), line to (307.13, 324.8), line to (287.93, 337.98) (closed) - Stroked with DeviceRgb(0.22, 0.365, 0.541)
```

---

As an aside, the above code uses the following imports:

```vb
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text
Imports iText.Kernel.Colors
Imports iText.Kernel.Geom
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, it helped me alot

Comment: your code helped me alot but I am stucked at a point, As you have mention many types of color in function GetColordata(). But I need to convert all these color types to RGB. I am not getting any solution to change these types of color into RGB. Please help me to get these color types in RGB.

Comment: Please make that a question in its own right. I'm not that familiar with all that color stuff, so I cannot sensibly answer this. Nonetheless one word of warning: Some of those color spaces contain colors that cannot be represented in RGB, merely approximated. Thus, your conversion will be lossy.